# Migrate D2D problems with files when databases on different servers

Tags: migrations

I am working on a complex Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 migration right now, and am leveraging [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Migrate D2D](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d).

Most of my content types have filefields on them.  I have my file and node migrations setup, and working nicely where the file migration is a dependency on my node migrations.

When my source and destination databases are running out of the same database server, then my migrations work.  When the source and destination databases are running out of different database servers, then my node migrations complain that there are unmet dependencies, even though `drush ms` shows that all of the file migrations ran (ie, no unprocessed items).

What causes this problem?  Is there a way to work around it?

In my instance, having both databases in the same server is a pretty suboptimal solution that I really would like to avoid.

Comment: is it possible the files haven't fully moved over yet (if you use the web interface for Migrate) and you're seeing something along the lines of: https://www.drupal.org/node/969056 Have you tried tweaking your batch sizes?

Comment: @tenken I don't think that is the problem.  If I all I do is change the connection info in settings.php for the source database, it will run.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm just curious (I work alot with Migrate but typically from legacydb -> drupal, or csv files) ...

Comment: @tenken Nope.  No clue what is going wrong here.